# Javascript from Java - document object

Tags: java, javascript, document, rhino, nashorn

I am trying to invoke a java script function that creates a html div structure by using e.g.

```
/* ... */
document.createElement("div");
/* ... */
```

Unfortunately I have no window and/or document object if I'm running this script directly from Java in contrast of running it in the browser. May somebody give me a piece of advise how to use or modify the javascript code? Is there a way to create a document object by myself? Thanks a lot.

Best regards

Sascha

Comment: I think you will have to build an xml document or even a string of html instead of actual DOM elements.

Answer (score 3):

Rhino and Nashorn do not supply browser objects like `window` and `document`. If you want those objects, you'll have to supply them yourself. Try [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), which provides implementations of those objects for the purposes of writing unit tests.